# ESlint and Salesforce

Tags: eslint

Does anyone know how to properly configure `eslint config file` and where to put it in Salesforce.
I need to disable some rules and I found that, for example, if I want to disable "ApexDoc" rule I can do that if in .eslintrc file just simply add this snippet of code

```
{
    "rules": {
        "ApexDoc": false
    }
}
```

but the problem is I get this error when I save .eslintrc file:

```
Unable to load schema from 'https://json.schemastore.org/eslintrc': Request vscode/content failed unexpectedly without providing any details.
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. That isn't the way to turn off an ESLint's rule, anyway "ApexDoc" is a rule of [Apex PMD](https://pmd.github.io/latest/pmd_rules_apex_documentation.html#apexdoc). Could you please clarify what's the issue and which tool you would like to configure?

Comment: Well, I mentioned "ApexDoc" only as an example but the problem is I can not write anything into .eslintrc because at the moment when I start to insert braces, letter or whatewer else immediately I get that error 
(Unable to load schema from 'https://json.schemastore.org/eslintrc': Request vscode/content failed unexpectedly without providing any details.
)

Comment: Could you please edit your question posting the whole `.eslintrc.json` file? Please provide also the content of  `settings.json` it's in the folder `%APPDATA%\Code\User`.

Comment: I resolved that issue, only by restarting my pc :/. But now I have one more question, do you maybe know how to disable some rules, for example, I want to disable this one "ClassNamingConventions". I don't want to show me warning related to that rule in .csv file downloaded after running sfdx scanner? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's another rule of Apex PMD. You cannot turn it off via ESLint, but you can define your own `ruleset.xml` with the rules you need, so if you don't include "ClassNamingConventions" it won't be active. This way you can customize rules priority too. Once you have your ruleset (you can start from a default one) you have to reference it in VS Code settings.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot...and is there any documentation how to reference it in VS Code settings?

Comment: File > Preferences > Settings > then type "ruleset" in the search bar. The last element should be "Apex PMD: Ruleset", there you can add the absolute path to your ruleset. Once done you can check your `settings.json` that is located at `C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Code\User` in which you should see something like `"apexPMD.rulesets": [ "C:\\A_FOLDER\\RULESET_FILE_NAME.xml" ]`